# Kali asks for login details repetively

Tags: virtualbox, kali-linux, login-screen

I have Kali 2020 installed in VirtualBox and all of a sudden, i opened the machine today, and i tried to login with a user's credentials.

But despite the fact that i use the correct username and password, Kali asks to type them again and again.

Specifically, the screen becomes black and then the login page shows up again.

I would really appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suppose you've tried to reboot your VM and still no go?

Comment: Yeah i tried to restart it, but again the same problem. And i didnt change anything.

Comment: Maybe you accidentally changed your keyboard layout, either on the host or the guest, and if your username is already displayed in the login window, you're typing the wrong password. Or you're in CapsLock without noticing it. Or both. Click on Other user, and type your username in the user area. You'll know right away which is which.

Comment: If i type a wrong password for the user, it says that password is incorrect. I rly dont know what to do and i rly want somehow to login again to this machine. I am in despare.

Comment: If you try to choose Other user, then enter your login name and password, you're just sent back to login?

Comment: I dont have an option to change user in the right upcorner. Only to reboot, shutdown etc.

Comment: Try to switch to a TTY and login from there. Then try to start the DE manually and see if you get some errors. Unfortunately I am not familiar with kali, so I cannot give you the exact commands.

Comment: Ok new update. I managed to login with root credentials. With the low priv users i cant login though. Any advice now that iam in the machine to solve this problem? Thanks in advance